# CSS: Trying to hide main menu link but not sub menu links

Tags: css

this little problem is driving me crazy even though it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

I have the following HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-763" class="hide-menu-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-95 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-763">
<a href="mainmenulink">MAIN MENU LINK</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-764" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-764">
<a href="submenulink1">SUB MENU LINK 1</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to apply a visibility:hidden to only the main menu link, but not to the submenu. I've applied a css class hide-menu-link to the main menu item. I've tried a lot, including the :not selector but something like li.hide-menu-link:not(ul.sub-menu li) a { visibility:hidden; } doesn't work.

Any tips are appreciated, I'm sure the solution must be super easy!

Comment: the thing is that the outer `li` elements has TEN css classes!!! Unless you put them all in a fiddler...it's pretty hard to help because we don't know how all these classes affect the child elements. Do you need all those classes at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the `a` direct descendant of `li.hide-menu-link`, using the `>` selector:

```
li.hide-menu-link > a {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* other CSS */
}
```

This selects all `a`'s that are immediate children of `li.hide-menu-link`:

```
<li class="hide-menu-link">
    <a>Will be styled</a> <!-- a direct/immediate descendant -->
    <div>
        <a>Will not be styled</a> <!-- not a direct/immediate descendant -->
    </div>
</li>
```

For a more detailed explanation of the `>` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: Thanks, the > selector indeed solved my problem; wasn't aware of this!

Comment: @joff19 If it helped you and if you think it would help others, feel free to mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

  <title>title
    <style>
      .hide-menu-link a {
        display: none;
      }
      #menu-item-764 a {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-763" class="hide-menu-link">
      <a href="mainmenulink">MAIN MENU LINK</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-764" class="">
          <a href="submenulink1">SUB MENU LINK 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

it does hide only first link. maybe you'll want to change the use of id to one of the sublinks classes instead